# UIView subclass throwing "Selector not found" when calling UIView+Category method

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I have subclass of UIView, MyView. I also have a category on UIView called UIView+simpleCategory.

This category declares a method doSomething

```
@interface UIView (simpleCategory)

- (void) doSomething;

@end
```

I'm having problems calling the doSomething method from the UIView subclass MyView. I get a "selector not recognized" error. I was wondering what I would need to do to have the subclass recognize its super class's category methods.

The problem arises when calling the UIView category method on an instance of my UIView subclass :

```
MyView *view = [[MyView alloc] init];
[view doSomething];        // throws selector not found error here
```

I'm wondering if I'm missing a #import somewhere but I would like to understand the relationship between Category and Subclasses.

THE SOLUTION ::

Apparently my implementation was fine. I just needed to add the category to the app target. I did this by clicking the category in the Project Navigator. Then I clicked the Utilities View (the view that slides out from the right side of the window) and checked the "Target Membership" checkbox in the File Inspector menu. This was all that needed to be done. Thanks everyone for the responses.

Comment: Are you getting an error when you compile, or an error at runtime?

Comment: are you importing the header file that declares the category?

Comment: I am getting an error during runtime. I do import the category into my subclass in the header file.

Comment: You're importing the category into MyView? That worked fine for me. Where are you calling MyView *view = [[MyView alloc] init];?

Comment: That's interesting. I'm calling it a line above where I'm calling doSomething.

Comment: Yes, I can see that, but in what class?  Also, are you sure that MyView is a UIView subclass? This should be working.

Comment: Is the implementation file for the category methods added to your target?

Comment: How would I check if the implementation file is added to the target?

Comment: nvm Carl I got it. I'll update my answer with the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your project is finding the header file declaring the UIView category — otherwise you'd get a compile-time warning.

But at run-time, it's not finding the category method. Check your UIView category implementation file to see which targets it goes into. I'm betting it's not included in your main target.

Comment: what do I need to do to see which targets the file goes into?

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's what I did to test this, and it worked.

The category:

```
@interface UIView (simpleCategory)

-(void)doSomething;

@end

@implementation UIView (simpleCategory)

-(void)doSomething {
    NSLog(@"Doing something");
}
```

I created a UIView subclass, MyView, to which I added no code except to import the category:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UIView+simpleCategory.h"

@interface MyView : UIView

@end
```

Then in my view controller viewDidLoad method:

```
MyView *view = [[MyView alloc] init];
[view doSomething];
```

Comment: I guess I'll simplify what I have down and test it like this. Then we can see where my problems lie.

Comment: This is the correct solution. The problem I was having came from the Category not being added to my target as described in some other comments/questions.

Comment: @atreat, did you copy your category file in from another project?  I don't know why it wouldn't be added to the correct target otherwise.  I didn't do anything but import the header file.

Comment: no I created it fresh. I have no idea why it wasn't added to the correct target. I have a single target in my project. I'm guessing I accidentally removed the file from the target.